# error TS2307: Cannot find module './message.service' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: angular

Creando una aplicación en angular obtengo este error al compilar. De echo es el tutorial de angular.

"error TS2307: Cannot find module './message.service' or its corresponding type declarations"

ya hay otros componentes y servicios importados y no presentan ningun problema.

**no se que puede pasar, porfa ayuda**

EN HERO.SERVICES

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
    import { Hero } from './hero';
    import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';
    import { MessageService } from './message.service';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root',
    })
    export class HeroService {

      constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { }

      getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
            this.messageService.add('HeroService: fetched heroes');
        return of(HEROES);
      }
    }
```

MESSAGE.SERVICES

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class MessageService {
  messages: string[] = [];

  add(message: string) {
    this.messages.push(message);
  }

  clear() {
    this.messages = [];
  }
}
```

TSCONFIG.JSON

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```